# Is "Bring to bear something" grammatically acceptable?

Tags: word-order

I assume that this sentence is correct:

> They **brought the full force of the law to bear** on anyone who criticized the government.

But is this one correct as well?

> They **brought to bear the full force of the law** on anyone who criticized the government.

I couldn't find the latter usage in the dictionaries, but I found one [on this page](http://books.google.com/books?id=8kYmz5-dXqwC&pg=PT37&lpg=PT37&dq=%22brought%20to%20bear%20his%20unjustified%20conviction%22&source=bl&ots=hY0H35cSC9&sig=QOYZp0yCiUV4MqBB9N4TiDflDdg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=czUSUpv5IdD2sgbkw4DoCQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22brought%20to%20bear%20his%20unjustified%20conviction%22&f=false). What's more interesting to me is to know whether we should follow the dictionaries or we can be creative with the order of "something"/"somebody" in similar phrases.

Comment: In this particular case I would say *No, you **can't*** arbitrarily re-order the wording you found in the dictionary. You can (just about) use *bring to bear* without specifying ***on what***, but separating *bring* and *on* sounds a bit like, say, *"?Jack and Jill went the hill up"*. Not what they call a "happy" construction (i.e. - it makes native speakers very unhappy to hear such things).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. I wish I could mark your comment as an accepted answer, but there's no button for that here.

Comment: I'll wait a while to see if someone else can give a more "generic" answer (I don't really know the correct terminology here, either). But as a general principle you probably shouldn't try "creatively" rearranging word order unless you've heard *more than one* native speaker use a form that doesn't match what you find in a dictionary. Often, what's involved here is a matter of idiomatic preference among native speakers, rather than "grammatical rules" as such, so you also need to be wary of picking up *non-idiomatic* variants from non-native speakers who simply don't know the "norm".

Comment: Note, FumbleFingers' notice still applies. Don't split *bear* and *on*. If the clause is too long/complex, use *they brought to bear on anyone, who... the full force of law blah blah blah*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar discourages that. Traditionalists will find it unacceptable, and in your case it would be bad form, considering "the full force of the law" is a fairly short and simple phrase.

This is acceptable though, and even recommended, if the phrase splitting the two words is long, complex, or nests multiple such splits.

What do I mean by nesting?

> He brought and put a force to be reckoned with to action to bear

No, that's terrible. Instead, use:

> He brought to bear and put to action a force to be reckoned with.