# what does "bring to bear" mean?

Tags: phrase-usage

Google defines **exert** as

> apply or bring to bear (a force, influence, or quality)

The dictionary has a example sentence:

> the moon exerts a force on the Earth

Can I paraphrase it as "the moon bring the Earth to bear a force"?

Comment: "The Moon bringS the Earth to bear a force" - It is not common to use it in short sentences, but I believe it is a valid sentence

Comment: @Amber But it does sound poetic. Isn't it?

Comment: [Here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/is-bring-to-bear-something-grammatically-acceptable) is another similar post of this topic on ELL, which may be helpful

Answer (score 4):

No. A better formation would be "The moon brings a force to bear on the Earth."

But "bring to bear" describes the application of an action where it did not previously exist, rather than a continuous action. So it would not be a good description of the moon's gravitational pull on the Earth, which has always existed.

Example from [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bring_to_bear): *The battleship brought her main guns to bear on the fort.*  (The battleship was not previously aiming at the fort, but now it is.)

Comment: But I think the second meaning in Wikitonary will be more appropriate."To apply; to employ something to achieve an intended effect."(Every possible pressure was brought to bear on the minister to ensure the unjust law was not passed.). What do you think?

Comment: @wangzhihao Well, that meaning implies there is a conscious actor applying the force, which is not the case here as relaxing has stated.

Comment: You can anthropomorphize the moon if it helps make your writing more clear -- "The moon brought to bear its light upon the city," while not strictly scientifically accurate, is a pretty image.  The key is to understand that "bring" implies moving the force from one place and applying it to another place. So "bringing the force of gravity to bear" just doesn't read right.

Comment: +1 what the moon is clearly not doing is bringing the earth to bear. It is gravity that is the object (if at all) rather than the earth.