# How to decompose 'bring to bear`?

Tags: idioms, auto-antonyms

I want to dredge below and ask not about [the definition](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/what-does-%E2%80%9Cto-bring-to-bear%E2%80%9D-mean/); I don't duplicate [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/19937/8712). I'd like to learn how to unravel 'bring to bear`, to determine its meaning (de novo).

For example, which definition of [bear](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bear) applies here? What's being brought?

Motivation: p 31, The English Legal System 2012-2013, Gary Slapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should look for at your link is not simple *bear* but *bear on*, about two-thirds of the way down the page, among the 'phrasal verbs'

> **bear on**
>   Be relevant to (something):
>   *two kinds of theories which bear on literary studies*

This is a narrowing of a once common sense of *bear* meaning ‘to exert force or pressure **on**’ > ‘to have an effect **on**’.

And that in turn is a very old transferred meaning; see [***OED 1***](http://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/732/mode/2up), senses III.26-32, which have this headnote:

> [This group seems to have arisen in a transference of the sense from *carry* to an action producing the same result (i.e. the moving forward of a body) by a different application of force, that of continuous pressure. This once established, the extension of the idea to pressure of many kinds, both horizontal and and vertical, followed. Thus there result senses of *bear* directly contrary to each other, as when a post bears the pressure which is brought to bear upon it, or a man bears up until calamity bears him down.]

To **bring** A **to bear on** B is thus to cause A to exert a force on B.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused. How does 'bear on' imply or induce 'bring to bear'?

Comment: Will you please to respond  in your answer, and not as comments?